# Can we connect to Sharepoint Rest Api through azure apim?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-api-management

Is it possible to connect SharePoint rest apis through azure apim backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect SharePoint rest apis through azure apim backend?

Yes we can connect to Sharepoint Rest Api through Azure Apim.

If Sharepoint have the REST endpoint or any of the supported backend then yes they can use APIM to call any REST endpoint (either Sharepoint or any).

You can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) for Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking to how to setup the sharepoint as backend in APIM. Do you know how I can authenticate sharepoint rest api from apim backend?